# typescript: dynamic property in object literal not working

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why is `A` allowed but not `B`?

```
declare type Observer<T = any> = (oldValue: T, newValue: T) => any;
declare type ObserverConfig<T extends object> = {
    [Key in keyof T]?: Observer<T[Key]>;
};

function someFunction<T extends { [key: string]: any }>()
{
    const prop: keyof T = 'someKey';
    const observer: Observer<T[keyof T]> = async () => {};

    // A
    const configA: ObserverConfig<T> = {};
    configA[prop] = observer;

    // B
    const configB: ObserverConfig<T> = {
        [prop]: observer,
    };
}
```

gived the following error:
[image]

Why is the key seen as a `string` in version `B` whilst `A` allows it?

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOabMm)

Comment: I've boiled down the example to the essence. You may want to update the question for it to be a bit more approachable. https://tsplay.dev/WGnlXm

Answer (score 0):

the key "prop" is already typed "keyof T"

just remove []

```
const configB: ObserverConfig<T> = {
    prop: observer,
};
```

Comment: `[prop]` and `prop` are going to result in a different object. One will be `{ someKey: observer }` while the other one will be `{ prop: observer }`

Answer (score 0):

When i try add another variable C TS infer type of C to `{ [x: string]: Observer<T[keyof T]>; }`

```
declare type Observer<T = any> = (oldValue: T, newValue: T) => any;
declare type ObserverConfig<T extends object> = {
    [Key in keyof T]?: Observer<T[Key]>;
};

function someFunction<T extends { [key: string]: any }>()
{
    let  prop: keyof T = 123;
    const observer: Observer<T[keyof T]> = async () => {};

    // A
    const configA: ObserverConfig<T> = {};
    configA[prop] = observer;

    // B
    const configB: ObserverConfig<T> = {
        [prop]: observer,
    };

    // C infer type
    const configC = { 
       [prop]: observer, 
    }; // { [x: string]: Observer<T[keyof T]>; }
}
```

The question is why type of C is `{ [x: string]: Observer<T[keyof T]>; }` ?
TS know that the value on the right of `=` is an object and its key is always a string (by JS Spec) hence C type is an object with key of type string and value of type `Observer<T[keyof T]>;`

While type of B is `{ [Key in keyof T]?: Observer<T[Key]> | undefined; }` for TS is those type mismatch.

In case of A, first the value match the type. Empty object have no key and type of `ObserverConfig<T extends object> = { [Key in keyof T]?: Observer<T[Key]> | undefined; }` since you have the `?` which mean key is optional.
Next line is also valid, be cause TS simply check that `prop` can be used on configA or not

```
    configA[prop] = observer;
```

Suggestion, you might need to change `key to string` instead.

Comment: Any specific reason the TS compiler interprets a `{ [prop]: observer }` object literal as `{ [x: string]: Observer<T[keyof T]> }`? I would expect the compiler to be a tad bit more smart since `prop` is explicitly of type `keyof T`. and for my B case the compiler would have 2 clues to correctly check the type 1) the type decleration on `const configB` and 2) a key of type `keyof T`